# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-google-oauth

I'm starting the app and getting this error:

> ```
>       email: req.user.emails[0].value,
>                             ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> ```

It was working good until I added the same code but for facebook login, it was reading and storing but I don't why it stopped.

**The code:**

```
router.get("/googleLogin/success", async (req, res)=>{
  
  if(req.user){
    const user = await User.findOne({provider_id: req.user.id, 
      provider: req.user.provider})
    if(user){
       res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "success",
        user: user
      })
      console.log("GOOGLE USER IS: " + user)
    }else{
      const checkUserEmail = await User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
      if(checkUserEmail){
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: "User already Exist with this email id",
        })
      }else{
        const user = await User.create({
          username: req.user.name.givenName+ "_" +req.user.name.familyName,
          firstName: req.user.name.givenName,
          lastName: req.user.name.familyName,

          // THE ERROR IS HERE
          
          email: req.user.emails[0].value,
          provider: req.user.provider,
          provider_id: req.user.id,
          profilePic: req.user.photos[0].value,
        });
         res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "success",
          user: user
        })
      }
    }
    console.log("CURRNT USER: ", user);
  }
})
```

Comment: check if req.user.emails is array type and check if req.user.emails is not null or empty

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `req.user.emails` is `undefined`.

You are likely missing the `email` scope in `profileFields` option.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
  clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
  callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback",
  passReqToCallback: true,
  profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name'] // emails needs to be listed here
}))
```

and

```
app.get('/connect/facebook', passport.authorize('facebook', {
  scope : ['email'], // list email here
}));
```

See [Passport-Facebook authentication is not providing email for all Facebook accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22880876/6943587)

Comment: Thank you for replying this answer will avoid me future errors, but the issue is that I'm getting the current error in (Google Auth) router.get("/googleLogin/success" and I have already scope: ["profile", "email"], in GoogleStrategy !!

Comment: Do you have the `enableProof` option set to true in `FacebookStrategy` options? See https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/11#issuecomment-29132801

Comment: just added it and it still giving me the same error!

Comment: Ok what if you use `email` instead of `emails` in the `profileFields` array?

Comment: also the same, when I call facebook login I get this http://localhost:3000/#_=_ it should be http://localhost:3000/ if success, and /facebookLogin/failed if failed, the question is why the error shows in google strategy instead of where it should be i mean in facebook strategy !!

Comment: So it looks like you provided just the routes for `googleLogin` as this issue so maybe you just need to provide the scopes for the google provider. See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/38412267/6943587 solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

kindly ensure you are writing the code for the Facebook strategy separately from the Google strategy and also check to see if you are not mixing up the two endpoints
for example:

```
router.get("/googleLogin/success", async (req, res)=>{}
```

should be called when using the google strategy and

```
router.get("/facebookLogin/success", async (req, res)=>{}
```

should be called when using the Facebook strategy.

also have it in mind that the endpoint in your callbackURL should be the same endpoint you call i.e if:

```
callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/facebookLogin/success"
```

then the endpoint to call would be:

```
/facebookLogin/success
```

if you still get the same error kindly post both the Facebook Strategy code and the Google Strategy code for a clear comparison

Comment: callbackURL should't be "/auth/facebook/callback" instead the one you mentioned?

Comment: I meant to ensure you call the same endpoint you specify in your callbackURL. the one I mentioned was just an example.